# Efficient (graph) aggregations in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Given a graph with interconnected entities:

[image]

What is the most efficient way to aggregate common Vertices based on Edges. For instance - with the given graph - return Musicians with an aggregated band count.

My current approach is aggregating post selection:

```
select m, count(b) as cnt from (match {class:Musician, as: m}<-currentMember-{as:b} return m, b) group by m order by cnt desc limit 10
```

But this looks highly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name, in('currentMember').size() as band from Musician order by band desc
```

Hope it helps

Regards